Use default theme values in tailwind matchUtilities plugin
I'd like to create a plugin that generates gradient borders. I came up with a solution that works, but It's not optimal yet. I configured my colors like so:

        primary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--primary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--primary-foreground))",
        },
        ring: "hsl(var(--ring))",
        secondary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--secondary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--secondary-foreground))",
        },

And here is the plugin:

export default bgBorderPlugin(({ matchUtilities, theme }) => {
  const borderBase = {
    borderStyle: "double",
    borderColor: "transparent",
    backgroundOrigin: "border-box",
    backgroundClip: "padding-box, border-box",
  };
  // Using `theme("colors.[name]", "")` to fallback on an empty string if color is not found, to avoid TS exception
  const gradient = `conic-gradient(
    from -47deg at 48.86% 48.52%,
    ${theme("colors.green.300", "")} 0deg,
    ${theme("colors.orange.200", "")} 50.625deg,
    ${theme("colors.stone.100", "")} 107.915deg,
    ${theme("colors.pink.400", "")} 156.275deg,
    ${theme("colors.violet.400", "")} 252.343deg,
    ${theme("colors.stone.100", "")} 282.483deg,
    ${theme("colors.green.300", "")}
  )`;

  matchUtilities(
    {
      // Name of the utility
      "bg-border": (value: string) => {
        // Extract background and border color
        let [bgColor, borderColor] = value.split(" ");

        // If no bg-color was defined, set default to gradient
        if (!bgColor) {
          bgColor = "gradient";
        }

        // Get bg-color (and its shade if any) from theme
        const color1 = theme(`colors.${bgColor.replace("-", ".")}`, "");

        // Construct bg-color as a conic gradient
        const color1Gradient =
          bgColor === "gradient"
            ? gradient
            : `conic-gradient(from -47deg, ${color1}, ${color1})`;

        // If no border-color was defined, set default to gradient
        if (!borderColor) {
          borderColor = "gradient";
        }

        // Get border-color (and its shade if any) from theme
        const color2 = theme(`colors.${borderColor.replace("-", ".")}`, "");

        // Construct border-color as a conic gradient
        const color2Gradient =
          borderColor === "gradient"
            ? gradient
            : `conic-gradient(from -47deg, ${color2}, ${color2})`;

        return {
          ...borderBase,
          backgroundImage: `${color1Gradient}, ${color2Gradient}`,
        };
      },
    },
    {},
  );
});


Unfortunately, this doesn't work when using the DEFAULT values: if I add the class bg-border-destructive-foreground , it works just fine, but bg-border-destructive won't: I'd have to type bg-border-destructivr-DEFAULT.
Is there a utility to get the actual computed color ?

How does destructive-foreground work? It doesn't seem like you have desctructive or foreground as defined values?

Also, you split values via space value.split(" "), but it does not seem you have any values passed to the matchUtilities()

I'm a little bit confused about what you are trying to achieve here, or how it has been working:

[…] if I add the class bg-border-destructive-foreground , it works just fine […]

I'm not sure how – you don't seem to have colors.destructive.foreground or colors.destructive-foreground as a value in your Tailwind configuration.
Furthermore, it does not seem like you're passing any values to matchUtilities().

From what I can discern, it seems like you're trying to create utility classes that use two colors. For this, I'd suggest creating a custom theme property configuration that has the pair of colors. We can derive this pair by providing default configuration.
We use this in conjunction with flattenColorPalette() to resolve the colors configuration to a flat dictionary. This will also resolve DEFAULT-keyed values for us:
import bgBorderPlugin from 'tailwindcss/plugin';
import flattenColorPalette from 'tailwindcss/lib/util/flattenColorPalette';

export default bgBorderPlugin(
  ({ matchUtilities, theme }) => {
    // …
  },
  {
    theme: {
      // This generates values like:
      // primary-primary: ['hsl(var(--primary))', 'hsl(var(--primary))'],
      // primary-primary-foreground: ['hsl(var(--primary))', 'hsl(var(--primary-foreground))'],
      borderGradient: ({ theme }) => {
        const colors = Object.entries(flattenColorPalette(theme('colors')));
        return Object.fromEntries(
          colors
            .flatMap(([bgName, bgColor]) => 
              colors.map(([borderName, borderColor]) => [
                `${bgName}-${borderName}`,
                [bgColor, borderColor]
              ])),
        );
      },
    },
  }
});

These color pairs will now be passed in as the value parameter for the matchUtilities function if we provide the values option with our borderGradient values:
matchUtilities(
  {
    "bg-border": ([bgColor, borderColor]) => {
      const color1Gradient =
        bgColor
          ? `conic-gradient(from -47deg, ${bgColor}, ${bgColor})`
          : gradient;

      const color2Gradient =
        borderColor
          ? `conic-gradient(from -47deg, ${borderColor}, ${borderColor})`
          : gradient;

      return {
        ...borderBase,
        backgroundImage: `${color1Gradient}, ${color2Gradient}`,
      };
    },
  },
  {
    values: theme('borderGradient'),
  },
);

See this working in this StackBlitz project.

Though again, still a bit unsure why there is a conic-gradient() that has two colors that are the same color as this wouldn't exhibit any gradient effect. I feel like one could use the built-in border color and background color utility classes instead, which would seem to give the same effect.
